# OAuth2 using angular angular-oauth2-oidc and SSO

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

This may be a case of me being exceptionally dense.

I've gone through all the steps in the following documentation: https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/

I've managed to get the remote html login page returned but the angular app is throwing a fit - namely:

```
error loading discovery document HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", etc. etc. etc.
```

and

```
core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers": {"normalizedNames":
```

this is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authConfig } from './metex/config/auth.config';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AnalyticsService } from './@core/utils/analytics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'metex-dashboard',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private analytics: AnalyticsService,
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
  ) {
    this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin();
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.analytics.trackPageViews();
  }
}
```

Please send help :)

Comment: share your auth.config.ts file please, i most cases with this error, it is about issuerurl which is wrong or issuer doesn't work. let see more information about your config file

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, although unfortunately it's not anything clever.  the Oauth I'm using has a custom step in it and the config file I SWEAR I copied, I didn't... as ever, pure user error.